# File obtained through FileSystemView.getFile(parent,false) return true both for isDirectory() and isFile()

Tags: java, windows, file

I'm wrinting a java desktop application with a file's search function like the windows file's browser. For this application i'm using the class FileSystemView from javax.swing.filechooser.*; 
After some testing i noticed that a File object got with the method FileSystemView.getFiles(parent,false); return true both for isFile() and isDirectory() methods of class File.

This file is a windows link to another folder under C:\

Instead a file (always a windows link) got with the same FileSystemView method but related to a .exe file return with the normal values.

I have all this links on my Desktop, here a sample routine for testing: 
(just put a link to a Folder and to a File in your desktop)

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        //get the FileSystemView instance and root files
        FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
        File[] rootList = fsv.getRoots();

        for(File root : rootList) {
            System.out.println("Root file: "+root.getName() +"       ("+root.getAbsolutePath()+")");
        //scan root childrens 
        File[] childrens = fsv.getFiles(root, true);
        if(childrens != null) {
            for(File atm : childrens) {
                System.out.println("\tScanning  "+root.getName()+"\\"+atm.getName());
                System.out.println("\t\t> isFile: "+atm.isFile()+"\tisDirectory: "+atm.isDirectory());
            }
        }
    }

    //this link (on my desktop) is pointing to a folder (under C:\\COLLAUDI)
    File windowsShortcutToFolder = new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\SIC\\Desktop\\COLLAUDI.lnk");

    //this link (on my desktop) is pointing to a file (under C:\\GestApp\\GeInt\\GeInt.exe)
    File windowsShortcutToFile = new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\SIC\\Desktop\\GeInt.lnk");

    //Here isFile and isDirectory return with the right values 
    System.out.println("\nScanning files properties: ");
    System.out.println("Scanning "+windowsShortcutToFolder);
    System.out.println("\t> isDirectory:"+windowsShortcutToFolder.isDirectory()
        +"\t> isFile:"+windowsShortcutToFolder.isFile());
    System.out.println("Scanning "+windowsShortcutToFile);
    System.out.println("\t> isDirectory:"+windowsShortcutToFile.isDirectory()
        +"\t> isFile:"+windowsShortcutToFile.isFile());
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Root file: Desktop (C:\Documents and Settings\SIC\Desktop)
Scanning Desktop\::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
    > isFile: false isDirectory: true
Scanning Desktop\::{208D2C60-3AEA-1069-A2D7-08002B30309D}
    > isFile: false isDirectory: true
Scanning Desktop\Documenti
    > isFile: false isDirectory: true
Scanning Desktop\COLLAUDI.lnk
    > isFile: true  isDirectory: true
Scanning Desktop\GeInt.lnk
    > isFile: true  isDirectory: false

Scanning files properties: 
Scanning C:\Documents and Settings\SIC\Desktop\COLLAUDI.lnk
    > isDirectory:false > isFile:true
Scanning C:\Documents and Settings\SIC\Desktop\GeInt.lnk
    > isDirectory:false > isFile:true
```

Why i got this values?

Comment: See https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/winxp.xml.

Comment: @VGR i have the same problem running this task on windows 7, and on another pc with windows xp and Java 7

Comment: @River `C:\\Documents and Settings` implies Windows XP.  Or an earlier version.